# No installation code email when installing OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

I have tried installing this utility on a couple of machines and I get to the section where I have to enter a code that you emailed but I am not receiving any email. I have of course checked in my spam folder and even tried different email addresses.

I emailed you but apparently this is the support method you use.

Comment: Hi David,
This might happened due to firewall configuration which might filtering emails. We sent you verification code by reply on your email query.


Thanks & Regards,
OpsHub Support

Comment: Thanks for this, I got the code from the email exchange.